# AntV Pie Chart Plot Click event referring to the initial state variable value , not accessing the updated state value

Tags: antv

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Select, Button } from 'antd';
import { Pie } from '@ant-design/plots';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedInputValue, setSelectValue] = useState('lucy');
  const [pieChartData, setPieChartData] = useState([
    { type: 'lucy-1', value: 12 },
    { type: 'lucy-2', value: 13 },
    { type: 'lucy-4', value: 2 },
    { type: 'lucy-3', value: 6 },
  ]);

  const config = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data: pieChartData,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 0.75,
    label: {
      type: 'spider',
      labelHeight: 28,
      content: '{name}\n{percentage}',
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    onReady: (plot) => {
      plot.on('element:click', (...args) => {
        console.log(selectedInputValue);
        updateChartValue();
      });
    },
  };

  const updateChartValue = () => {
    if (selectedInputValue === 'lucy') {
      const data = [
        { type: 'lucy-1', value: 12 },
        { type: 'lucy-2', value: 13 },
        { type: 'lucy-4', value: 2 },
        { type: 'lucy-3', value: 6 },
      ];
      setPieChartData(data);
    } else if (selectedInputValue === 'jack') {
      const data = [
        { type: 'jack-1', value: 12 },
        { type: 'jack-2', value: 13 },
        { type: 'jack-4', value: 2 },
        { type: 'jack-3', value: 6 },
      ];
      setPieChartData(data);
    } else if (selectedInputValue === 'Yiminghe') {
      const data = [
        { type: 'Yiminghe-1', value: 12 },
        { type: 'Yiminghe-2', value: 13 },
        { type: 'Yiminghe-4', value: 2 },
        { type: 'Yiminghe-3', value: 6 },
      ];
      setPieChartData(data);
    } else {
      const data = [
        { type: 'dummy-1', value: 12 },
        { type: 'dummy-2', value: 13 },
        { type: 'dummy-4', value: 2 },
        { type: 'dummy-3', value: 6 },
      ];
      setPieChartData(data);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSelectValue(value);
    sdddd = value;
  };

  return (
    <div id="chart">
      <Select
        value={selectedInputValue}
        style={{
          width: 120,
          marginLeft: '12px',
          marginTop: '12px',
        }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
        <Option value="Dummy">Dummy</Option>
      </Select>

      <Pie {...config} />
      <Button onClick={updateChartValue}>Load Data </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The variable pieChartData should get loaded based on selectedInputValue when performing the plot.on("element:click") event. But, On the pie chart element click, the state variable **selectedInputValue** holds the initialized value only.
Other places outside the events of the charts are all able to access the new updated value for selectedInputValue.
Any thoughts on this?